# Elixir parse binary data?

Tags: erlang, elixir

​for example:

I have a binary look like this:

```
 bin1 = "2\nok\n3\nbcd\n\n"​
```

or

```
 bin2 = "2\nok\n3\nbcd\n1\na\n\n"​
```

and so on...

The format is

```
 byte_size  \n  bytes \n byte_size  \n  bytes \n  \n
```

I want parse binary get

```
  ["ok", "bcd"]
```

how to implement in  Elixir or Erlang ?

#### Go version

a Go version parse this

```
func (c *Client) parse() []string {
    resp := []string{}
    buf := c.recv_buf.Bytes()
    var idx, offset int
    idx = 0
    offset = 0

    for {
        idx = bytes.IndexByte(buf[offset:], '\n')
        if idx == -1 {
            break
        }
        p := buf[offset : offset+idx]
        offset += idx + 1
        //fmt.Printf("> [%s]\n", p);
        if len(p) == 0 || (len(p) == 1 && p[0] == '\r') {
            if len(resp) == 0 {
                continue
            } else {
                c.recv_buf.Next(offset)
                return resp
            }
        }

        size, err := strconv.Atoi(string(p))
        if err != nil || size < 0 {
            return nil
        }
        if offset+size >= c.recv_buf.Len() {
            break
        }

        v := buf[offset : offset+size]
        resp = append(resp, string(v))
        offset += size + 1
    }

    return []string{}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

A more flexible solution:

```
result = bin 
|> String.split("\n") 
|> Stream.chunk(2)
|> Stream.map(&parse_bytes/1)
|> Enum.filter(fn s -> s != "" end)

def parse_bytes(["", ""]), do: ""
def parse_bytes([byte_size, bytes]) do
  byte_size_int = byte_size |> String.to_integer
  <<parsed :: binary-size(byte_size_int)>> = bytes
  parsed
end
```

Comment: thanks, I add a version to description this question

Comment: Note that this solution is not good for parsing a large amount of data because it will iterate over several times. The 2nd solution in lidashuang's answer will avoid that issue.

Comment: I've updated mine to use the `Stream` functions instead of `Enum`. This will sidestep the multiple iteration issue as well.

Comment: note that in newer elixir versions you will have to write `binary-size(byte_size_int)` instead of `[binary, size(byte_size_int)]`

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a solution:

```
  defp parse("\n") do
    []
  end

  defp parse(data) do
    {offset, _} = :binary.match(data, "\n")
    size = String.to_integer(binary_part(data, 0, offset))
    value = binary_part(data, offset + 1, size)

    len = offset + 1 + size + 1
    [value] ++ parse(binary_part(data, len, byte_size(data) - len))
  end
```

The Elixir mailing list provides another one:

```
  defp parse_binary("\n"), do: []

  defp parse_binary(binary) do
    {size, "\n" <> rest} = Integer.parse(binary)
    <<chunk :: [binary, size(size)], "\n", rest :: binary>> = rest
    [chunk|parse_binary(rest)]
  end
```